# Lravel-Vue multiple image upload error--Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload multiple image using laravel & vue js. but when I click upload I am getting an error saying "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array"

on my vue file---

```
<input type='file' @change="selectFile"/>
```

the methods are--

```
selectFile(e) {
   this.images.push(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

the submit method is---

```
 publishAd() {
                    let formData = new FormData();
                    this.images.forEach((file) => {
                        formData.append('images[]' + file, file.name);
                    });
                 axios.post('/common/publish-ad', formData, {
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                            }
                        }).then((response) => {
                             console.log(response.data);
                        })
                       
                },
```

on my controller---

```
$images=array();
        $files= $request->images;

        // dd($files);
        // if($files){
            $i=0;
            foreach($files as $file){
                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileNameExtract=explode('.',$name);
                $fileName=$fileNameExtract[0];
                $fileName.=time();
                $fileName.=$i;
                $fileName.='.';
                $fileName.=$fileNameExtract[1];
                $file->move('storage/Ad_list/',$fileName);
                $images[]=$fileName;
                $i++;
            }
            $ad['photos'] = implode(",",$images);

            $ad->save();
        // }
```

on the log I got the images array---

```
'images' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'object File' => 'dodo.png',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'object File' => 'orchid-ps.png',
    ),
  ),
```

How do I solve the problem of -- Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array???